# USB external drive is recognized in solaris 11

Tags: usb, solaris

New external USB drive is formatted (Fat32) and useable on one Solaris x86 unix computer.  Move it to another unix computer (same make and model) and it does not recognize the usb drive. All ports are turned on and usable by other devices.  If I connect the dribve back to the origional maching it works fine.  This external drive needs to be seen by both Windows and Unix machines.  I have tested the cables and they work fine. lsusb does not seem to be supported on Solaris 11, I have been doing a df -h command to see the drive is mounted.  Not sure how to check to see what the kernel is reporting?

Comment: Zero information given. Does `lsusb` see it, what versions of usb, is it a `mount` problem, cable problem or port problem? What file system is involved. As an aside, my car is broken, does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: @RichterT that's all crucial information that should be part of the question! Please **edit** the question to include this!

Comment: @RichterT please update the question rather than put pertinent info in comments. I have no experience of Sol11, but is this Sparc or x86_64? Are the USB drivers loaded? Do the ports work with other usb equipment?

Comment: Does Sol11 have `lsusb` equivalent? What is the kernel reporting?